# I get Bad Authentication data when I try to send a DM via REST request

Tags: rest, twitter

After running

`curl --request POST 
--url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json 
--header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_nonce="AUTO_GENERATED_NONCE", oauth_signature="AUTO_GENERATED_SIGNATURE", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="AUTO_GENERATED_TIMESTAMP", oauth_token="USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"' 
--header 'content-type: application/json' 
--data '{"event": {"type": "message_create", "message_create": {"target": {"recipient_id": "RECIPIENT_USER_ID"}, "message_data": {"text": "Hello World!"}}}}'`
 
I got this error:

`{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}` back.

Where do you set your access token & access token secret? And how do you add Quick Replies?

Comment: This is a bit complicated to do with curl on its own, but Twitter has a tool called [twurl](https://github.com/twitter/twurl) which is similar, that can do the authentication for you. How have you generated all of the signatures required? Quick replies are part of the event data, per the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/quick-replies/overview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61614327/10011954 Works, too. Got it working with an REST Client called Insomnia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh got it! YES!

````
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json \
  --header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="CALLBACK_URL", oauth_consumer_key="KEY", oauth_nonce="auto generated", oauth_signature="autogenerated", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="current time stamp", oauth_token="TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --cookie 'personalization_id=SOME COOKIE; guest_id=SOME ID; lang=en' \
  --data '{
  "event": {
    "type": "message_create",
    "message_create": {
      "target": {
        "recipient_id": "ID"
      },
      "message_data": {
        "text": "What'\''s your favorite type of bird?",
        "quick_reply": {
          "type": "options",
          "options": [
            {
              "label": "Red Bird",
              "description": "A description about the red bird.",
              "metadata": "external_id_1"
            },
            {
              "label": "Blue Bird",
              "description": "A description about the blue bird.",
              "metadata": "external_id_2"
            },
            {
              "label": "Black Bird",
              "description": "A description about the black bird.",
              "metadata": "external_id_3"
            },
            {
              "label": "White Bird",
              "description": "A description about the white bird.",
              "metadata": "external_id_4"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'```
````